junit 4 tests throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
And Hi,I have a java project with the following structure:
packagename  
---src  
------main (contains source for package classes)  
------test (contains source for test classes)  
---bin  
------main  
-------test  
---lib (contains junit4 and hamcrest JAR files). 

Each test file is NOT declared to be part of the package packagename.
I am unable to run any test class (I have tried several of the test classes I have written) as any attempt to run them will throw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' with one of the 'user-defined' classes in the package.
I am compiling each test file (successfully) with the following command:
'/src/test $ javac -cp .:../../bin:../../lib/junit-4.13.2.jar -d ../../bin/test TestClassName.java'

And attempting to run a test class with the following command, taken from How to run JUnit test cases from the command line:
'/bin/test $ java -cp .:../main:../../lib/junit-4.13.2.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClassName.'

This results in the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cards/MyClass
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:557)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:27)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:98)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cards.EmptyDeckException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:528)
    ... 10 more


I am not using an IDE nor a build system like maven. I have experimented with modifying the classpath when running junit (for example including all source files) but the same result occurs. My understanding is that if the classpath contains the binary files for the user-defined classes then junit should be able to find them when running tests. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You need to add the location of the class you're trying to test (and all its dependencies) to the classpath...
